# XSLT: Choose defined variable with "when test"

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to choose a defined variable ($last for last name) for the player (parent node) in a list of 20 or so, under a test looking for the existence of a specific child node. There can only be one instance of this child node per XML.

Here's an excerpt from the source code:

```
  <player name="FOX, Mason" shortname="FOX, Mason" uni="2" gp="1" gs="1" spot="1" code="1" bats="R" throws="R" class="FR" pos="cf" atpos="cf" playerId="e5e9a2dh92nl74wn"> 
  <hitting r="0" h="0" ab="3" rbi="0" bb="1" so="2" fly="1" kl="1" hitdp="1"></hitting>  
  <fielding po="1" a="0" e="0"></fielding>  
  ....

<player name="SELLERS, Wil" shortname="SELLERS, Wil" uni="24" gp="1" sub="1" spot="10" code="0" bats="R" throws="R" class="SO" pos="p" atpos="p" playerId="21jhmtg1nlxdrwda"> 
  <hitting r="0" h="0" ab="0" rbi="0"></hitting>  
  <fielding po="1" a="0" e="0"></fielding>  
  <hsitsummary></hsitsummary>  
  <pitching appear="2" ip="4.0" ab="13" bb="2" bf="15" fly="1" ground="4" h="1" so="7" save="1"></pitching>  
  <psitsummary fly="1" ground="4" picked="0" leadoff="0,4" wrunners="0,3" vsleft="1,6" w2outs="0,4"></psitsummary>  
  <fsituation po="1"></fsituation> 
</player>
```

And here's the code I've come up with.

```
<Save>
            <xsl:for-each select="player">
            <xsl:variable name="full_name" select="@name"/>
            <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-after($full_name, ',')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="last" select="substring-before($full_name, ',')" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="pitching/@save">
                    <name_tag>SV:&#160;<xsl:value-of select="$last"/>&#160;(<xsl:value-of select="pitching/@save"/>)</name_tag>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>SV: None</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Save>
```

It's working great for games without a save (the singular occurrence node I'm searching for). For games with a save, however, it selects the proper value for save alongside the first name in the player list instead of the player's name directly above the selected node. I have no doubt I'm close - since it mostly works - but I can't figure out how to tell it to select the right player's name.

Thanks.

Comment: This xslt code looks like it is executed not in the context of a player node but one level above (because you use `player/@name' which selects all players' name attributes). Rewrite the xslt code (we can see only a small snippet of it) so that the Save is generated in the context of a player node and then you only have (the right?) one.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying. This code is now selecting the right player for games with a save, but now it won't spit out the 'otherwise' component when there isn't one. Updated code above.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't exactly understand the problem The variable `last` will always be defined before the `choose/when`. Do you want to check if is empty or what? I suggest you try with an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My apologies if I'm not being clear. Perhaps it might help if I give the desired output for each instance. For games with a save: 'SV: $last (#)'. For games without a save: 'SV: None'. Is there any way to include the variable within the choose/when? Or is that not possible?

Comment: So yes, I want to check if it is empty. If it is not, choose the 'SV: $last (#)' info. If it is empty, 'SV: None'.

Comment: Sure you can test the variable in the when condition, like `<xsl:when test="$last = ''"/>`

Comment: Ah ok. Do you need to specify a certain value in the when test, or will it automatically grab the $last variable for the chosen player with just that string?

Comment: There is only one variable at the place where the when is. The one that is declared in that context. If you create that variable here for the chosen player, it will contain that; the value will differ in each `for-loop` iteration. Just try it.